# How does React know if a function component is a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React supports both class and function components. All React files have an `import React from ‘react’` statement at the top. When creating a class component (like so: `class MyClassComponent extends React.Component ...`), there is an explicit mention of which class this class instance extends from. However, when declaring a function component (`const MyFunctionComponent = () => ()`), it isn’t being explicitly said “hey this is a React component by the way.”

For all we know, this could be a function in plain JavaScript. How then, does React recognize functions as function components?

Comment: "The simplest way to define a component is to write a JavaScript function." If the function accepts at least a single prop, then React will recognize it as a functional component.

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't do that, every function is valid, if it returns a valid type. However, React doesn't check statically if a function will return something valid, so it just runs it, if it's a function. In newer React versions the return value can be nearly everything. Arrays work now, strings also. Currently React does support the following types as return values:

- React elements. Typically created via JSX. An element can either be a representation of a native DOM component (), or a user-defined composite component ().
- String and numbers. These are rendered as text nodes in the DOM.
- Portals. Created with ReactDOM.createPortal.
- null. Renders nothing.
- Booleans. Render nothing. (Mostly exists to support return test &&  pattern, where test is boolean.)
- Fragment (array of valid elements)

So, unless you don't return undefined, it should work, but as said, it will execute it always if it is a function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for the [isValidElement()](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L364) function. In a nutshell, they check if it is an object (functions are objects) with a `$$typeof` of the `REACT_ELEMENT_TYPE` Symbol.

Beyond that though, it doesn't really matter if it is a normal function or not. For the most part, even if I make some random function, as long as it has a `render()` function, it'd be usable as a React element. I'm not sure if they have checks for missing lifecycle functions or not, but if they do, then it would work (if they don't, it'd throw errors).

When it comes to JavaScript "inheritence", it always just boils down to if the shape of the object matches the expected shape.

Comment: I think you missed the point, isValidElement() doesn't determine if a stateless function is valid.

Comment: Indeed, which is why I mentioned beyond that, it doesn't really matter since any function will work.

Comment: but function components can go without an explicit `render()` method. sooo, they work as long as they return an acceptable return value?

Comment: @JaySeeCode exactly.

Answer (score 1):

But it **IS** a plain javascript **function**. It simply return a value which is then interpreted by React.

Edit: To help you understand, you need to keep in mind that in JavaScript EVERYTHING (except of course primitive types) are objects (Classes, Functions, Arrays, etc) are at the end all the same.